# Get-spproduct -local stuck

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, administration, cumulative-update, stsadm

I launched a `get-spproduct -local` command through PowerShell with the farm account, however, it ran now for almost one hour.
Got the same behaviour with `stsadm -o localupgradestatus`. It just runs and never stops until I kill the cmd/PowerShell window.
What could block the jobs?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the event viewer? ULS logs?

Comment: This article might give you an idea what would this cmdlet look into when being executed:  https://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/12/the-magic-of-get-spproduct-local/ Still, we will need error messages or logs to identify the issue.